# Transpose of tables in SQL without aggregate function

Tags: sql, pivot

I tried at end my end to get the expected output with below query but getting error. I am using Pivot but I can't use aggregate function here. Can it be done without using Pivot?

```
       select * from employee;
```

[image]

desired output :

[image]

My Code :

```
select * from (
select team_name, emp_name from employee
)
Pivot 
(
 emp_name
 for team_name
 IN(
    'king_cobra',
    'MFD',
    'Risk Ops',
    'scorpion_king'
   )
);
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are are using.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want pivoting.  You want to store four separate team registries in four separate *columns*.  That is rather messy, but you can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when team_name = 'king_cobra' then emp_name end) as king_cobra,
       max(case when team_name = 'MFD' then emp_name end) as MFD,
       max(case when team_name = 'Risk Ops' then emp_name end) as Risk_Ops,
       max(case when team_name = 'scorpion_king' then emp_name end) as scorpion_king
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by team_name order by emp_name) as seqnum
      from employee e) e
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: What's the need of seqnum in this query?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph My guess is that it `seqnum` is needed for the grouping, and the final line should in fact be `group by seqnum;`

Comment: And to elaborate on what why `seqnum` is needed for the group by (if not for your benefit, for the benefit of future readers). You always have to use an aggregate with an transposition, to deal with the fact that there could be multiple candidate rows for a single column. The way to deal with this is to make sure that you ensure every row within a group is uniquely identifiable. `Seqnum` achieves this by creating a unique identifier within each tea, this means where there is more than one person in a team, it generates more than one row to display them.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph . . . Clearly it is being used for the aggregation.  It defines the rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH
    ints(n) as (
      select 1 as n
      union all
      select n+1 from ints where n<5)
select n, 
    n1.emp_name as 'king_cobra', 
    n3.emp_name as 'MFD', 
    n4.emp_name as 'Risk Ops', 
    n2.emp_name as 'scorpio_king'
from ints
left join
  (select row_number() over(order by emp_name) x, emp_name
  from employee where team_name='king_cobra') n1 on n1.x=n
left join
  (select row_number() over(order by emp_name) x, emp_name
  from employee where team_name='scorpion_king') n2 on n2.x=n
left join
  (select row_number() over(order by emp_name) x, emp_name
  from employee where team_name='MFD') n3 on n3.x=n
left join
  (select row_number() over(order by emp_name) x, emp_name
  from employee where team_name='Risk Ops') n4 on n4.x=n
order by n
```

The 'best' (??? ) solution, using PIVOT i got is:

```
select row, emp_name, "king_cobra",    "MFD",    "Risk Ops",    "scorpion_king"
from (
    select emp_name, team_name, row_number() over (partition by team_name order by emp_name) as ROW
from employee
    ) AS SourceTable
Pivot 
(
 MIN(team_name)
 for team_name
 IN("king_cobra",    "MFD",    "Risk Ops",    "scorpion_king"    )

) AS PivotTable;
```

which gives:

```
row                  emp_name  king_cobra     MFD            Risk Ops       scorpion_king
-------------------- --------- -------------- -------------- -------------- --------------
1                    Abhishek  NULL           NULL           NULL           scorpion_king
1                    Akshay    NULL           NULL           Risk Ops       NULL
1                    Ankit     king_cobra     NULL           NULL           NULL
1                    Deepanshu NULL           MFD            NULL           NULL
1                    Himanshu  NULL           NULL           NULL           NULL
2                    Arran     king_cobra     NULL           NULL           NULL
2                    Harshita  NULL           NULL           NULL           scorpion_king
3                    CS        king_cobra     NULL           NULL           NULL
3                    Himanshu  NULL           NULL           NULL           scorpion_king
4                    Gaurav    king_cobra     NULL           NULL           NULL
```

Comment: and i have problems reading you image, because it's not plain text....

Comment: But `('Abhishek' ,'scorpion_king'), 
('Akshay' ,'Risk Ops'), 
('Arran' ,'king_cobra'), 
('Ankit' ,'king_cobra'), 
('CS' ,'king_cobra'), 
('Deepanshu' ,'MFD'), 
('Gaurav' ,'king_cobra'), 
('Harshita' ,'scorpion_king'), 
('Himanshu' ,'scorpion_king'), 
('Himanshu' ,'Singh Risk Ops')` is soo much more readable...   (for testing, and giving a 'proper' answer)

Comment: Then answer is given here: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-pivoting-on-non-numeric-data-types/.    In other words 'in standard MSSQL it is not possible to PIVOT on non-numeric columns'

Comment: But, I am using Oracle DB.

Comment: If you used `MIN(emp_name)` inside your pivot function rather than `MIN(team_name)` I think your pivot solution would provide the desired results